# Spring Security hasIpAddress causes errors

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

In my configuration, I have defined that:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
```

And with the following code:

```
    http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/payment").permitAll()
            //.antMatchers("/api/payment").hasIpAddress("XXX.XXX.X.XX")
...
```

Now, when I have permited all traffic to '/api/payment', everything gets executed.

However, if I try to enable the IP verification:

```
    http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            //.antMatchers("/api/payment").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/payment").hasIpAddress("XXX.XXX.X.XX")
...
```

The requests send from the given IP address receive the following response:

```
{"errorMessage":"Not Found","errorId":"6ae34aa3-9195-42d6-8906-996906988ce0","errorDetails":null}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This is the method that I am invoking:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payment", method = POST)
public String saveOrder(@ModelAttribute PaymentDto paymentDto) {
    paymentService.savePayment(paymentDto);
    return "OK";
}
```

Since I always send request data (for example, the post is on the following url: `api/payment?id=123&whatever`)

I've added:

```
.antMatchers("/api/payment?**").access("hasIpAddress('XXX.XXX.X.XX')")
```

But this didn't worked neither.

**UPDATE 2**

I've changed placement of my antMatcher like this:

```
http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/app/**", "/assets/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/authentication/login", "/login.html").anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/api/products/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/cities/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/order/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/payment").hasIpAddress("XXX.XXX.X.XX")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new CsrfRequestMatcher())
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login.html")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/authentication/login")
        .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/authentication/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
        .deleteCookies(JSESSIONID_COOKIE, CSRF_COOKIE)
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .permitAll();
```

Which now just redirects me to the login page when I am trying to make a post from the given Ip Address

Comment: Probably you're getting a nullpointerexception

Comment: @reos, there is no nullpointerexception. the method is not executed at all.

Comment: Probably the IP is null and spring throws the nullpointer

Comment: how can IP address be a null?

Comment: I don't know how spring gets the IP address. Do you have a way to know the IP that Spring is getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I turned out, I was receiving the request via proxy from nginx, which wasn't passing the original IP address of a requester. I had to add some additional nginx configuration, and now, I can verify IP address like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payment", method = POST)
public String saveOrder(PaymentDto paymentDto, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For").equals("XXX.XXX.X.XX")){
      DO STUFF
    }
}
```

Comment: you might want to accept your own answer ;-)