# Failed to evaluate expression 'hasIpAddress(..)' in PreAuthorize

Tags: spring, spring-security

In the pursuit of finding an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897180/spring-security-hasipaddress-causes-errors?noredirect=1#comment67085139_39897180) question, I've been playing around with the ways to filter request based on the Ip Address. 
I have the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payment", method = POST)
@PreAuthorize("hasIpAddress('XXX.XXX.X.XX')")
public String pay(PaymentDto paymentDto){
    System.out.println("Payment received");
    return "OK";
}
```

However, at execution, this throws me an error of:

```
{"errorMessage":"Internal Server Error","errorId":"26b1a1ba-3ae8-4497-9f1c-7370ea5116ff","errorDetails":{"message":"Failed to evaluate expression 'hasIpAddress('XXX.XXX.X.XX')'","exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","errors":null}}
```

What is going on?

This is Java error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 0): Method call: Method hasIpAddress(java.lang.String) cannot be found on org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot type
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:211) ~[spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:125) ~[spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:85) ~[spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131) ~[spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html), hasIpAddress is Web Security Expression and not available for @PreAuthorize.
>    You can use like this

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*"
        access="hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('xxx.xx.xx.xxx')"/>
    ...
  </http>
```

or

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/tokens").access(
            "hasIpAddress('xxx.x.xx.xx'))
```

But not as

```
@PreAuthorize("hasIpAddress('XXX.XXX.X.XX')")
public String pay(PaymentDto paymentDto){
```